# Authentication in a .net http handler

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing an http request handler in .net to upload files from client to a remote folder. Both client and server parts works fine, and now I have to handle authentication. 
The code so far:

Client:

```
private void uploadFile(string fileName)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string fullWebServiceURI = @"http://localhost:999/FileUpload.ashx?fileName=" + fileName;
        client.UploadFile(fullWebServiceURI, fullFilePath);
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class FileUpload : IHttpHandler {

    private const string SERVER_UPLOAD_FOLDER = "App_Data";

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"];
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            foreach(string key in files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[key];
                string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath(SERVER_UPLOAD_FOLDER), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(fullFilePath);
            }
        }

        // Output
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Credentials are stored in a database on the remote server but I can't figure out how to pass them from client.

I don't want to pass credentials in the query string, so I tried setting the Credentials property of WebClient like this:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usr", "pwd");
```

but in the http handler I'm unable to retrieve those informations.

Can anybody help me?

SOLUTION:

Thanks to Frebin Francis, i started investigating on headers and i find out that the trick was just like this:

```
 string authHeader = context.Request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString()].Substring(6);
 string[] creds = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader)).Split(':');
```

setting credentials with NetworkCredentials class alredy put them in the authorization's header section, and the value can be easily retrieved as shown above.
Notice that this is Basic authentication mechanism, that consists in 2 steps:
1. First request, the server send back a 401 status code to query for credentials. I handle it with:

```
if (context.Request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString()] == null)
{
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
    context.Response.End();
}
```

2. Client send another request with authorization header section.

@Jakub Holovsky: username and password will be encrypted, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Best method is to pass your credentials in request Header.

Comment: Passing unencrypted credentials is always dangerous. I would recommend using different technique to authenticate against your server.

Comment: You should also move the solution to be an answer below not in the same question